# Web Audio API and Bluetooth

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bluetooth, web-audio-api

I programmmed a website which uses text to speech engine to generate audio files.

Then these mp3 files are started using Web Audio API.

Everything works fine when hearing aufio from speakers on a computer or on a smart phone.

However, as soon as I connect my bluetooth helmet to the smart phone, the audio is not played.

Is it a famous issue that Web  Audio API doesn't work with bluetooth devices, or does the issue come from my code?

Do I need to change the context's destination ? How can I set it to buetooth? (ex : https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/)

> source.connect(context.destination);       // connect the source to the context's destination (the speakers)

Thanks,

LL

Comment: Hi, almost the same problem for me, did you find a solution?

Comment: I had the same problem as well. I was using Howler.js at the time and I realised when I used "html5:true" [option](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#options) the audio was fine. So it seems like when you use Web Audio API the browser plays the the sound file (since you can still get onComplete, onUpdate etc. events) however you don't hear the output on bluetooth device. It is got to be a decoding issue. I still haven't found an official bug report for this but please let us know if you had come across something.

Comment: I have the very same issue. I created an Angular 9 app using Tone.js and it works fine on the phone speaker but remains silent when the bluetooth device is connected.

Comment: I filed an issue at https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/issues/646

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this issue?  Appears to be old, but haven't found a solution yet.  Is it a browser issue?  Possibly not implemented yet?

Comment: Oh.. I have the same problem :(